# Что называется статической инициализацией массива?

Tags: java, массивы, syntax

Это?

```
 String[] seasons  = new String[] {"Winter", "Spring", "Summer", "Autumn"};
```

Или это?

```
 String[] seasons  = {"Winter", "Spring", "Summer", "Autumn"};
```

Или и то и другое?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Или так

```
static final String[] seasons;

static {
  seasons = new String[] {"Winter", "Spring", "Summer", "Autumn"};
}
```

Answer (score 2):

Я бы ответил так:

```
static final String[] seasons = new String[] {"Winter", "Spring", "Summer", "Autumn"};
```

и

```
static final String[] seasons = {"Winter", "Spring", "Summer", "Autumn"}
```